Blender renders the black background in a very... strange way?
I literally never seen this before.

Why does this happen? Does someone know a fix?
Blendfile:


Picture your self reading this Question as it was asked by somebody else. How big could be a chance to answer this Q  and be right. Result like this can be achieved many ways and we don't know nothing about your setup, app version, etc ... please share your simplified blend just with a single object if issue persist. blend-exchange.com

@vklidu I added the blend file

You have a ridiculously high light Power setting in the file that you uploaded (250000 w). What setting are you using in the image that you posted?

The weird appearance comes from the ridiculously high Power of the light in combination with the Denoise option. I guess Blender calculates some stray light particles reflected from the object all over the image and the Denoise makes some muddy overall low brightness of it. I draw this conclusion from the fact that this effect becomes less intense when you lower the Power of the light and even disappears completely when you disable denoising or make the object invisible so that there is no more surface getting hit by light.

Also removing the multires modifier removes the problem in this case.

If your Q is referring to the brighter streaks in black around objects, than Gordon's comment sounds to me right ... for sure if your screen was rendered with black plane under those "white" objects (blend you shared, doesn't contain this plane so I don't have the issue seen in your screen.
